# Highchart - position the div text parallel to the bars

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to position the div text adjacent to the bars. 
How to set the div?

I have tried like set the divs as position absolute and top value has been taken like the following after chart rendered.

```
      $.each(series, function (i, s) {
          debugger;
          $.each(s.points, function (j, p: any) {
            debugger;
            topPosition.push(p);
          });
        });


topPosition[index].dataLabel.translateY
```

But for the stacked bar, this is not working.
**Which is the best idea to get the positions and set the our div next to highchart bars based on the rendered chart?**

[Working Sample for bar chart](https://plnkr.co/edit/kpcITT2nMR24KR62kiJy?p=preview)

[Non-working sample for stacked bar](https://plnkr.co/edit/cOh986a33xHYkh5TJeq1?p=preview)

**Expected Result:**
[image: Expected result]

Answer (score 0):

You can find the vertical position for the external div with this formula:

```
div.style.top = chart.plotSizeX - point.plotX + chart.plotTop + 'px';
```

Plot area is rotated (90 degrees) so we have to use `chart.plotSizeX` and `point.plotX` instead of `chart.plotSizeY` and `point.plotY`. In this case `chart.plotSizeX` is the height of the plot area, `point.plotX` is the point's distance from the **bottom** of the plot area. `chart.plotTop` doesn't change - it describes how far is the plot area from the top bottom of the chart.

**Example:**

HTML:

```
<div id="adjacentToBar" style="position: absolute; background: red; width: 100px; height: 20px;">
Hello
</div>
```

JS:

```
var div = document.getElementById('adjacentToBar'),
  point = chart.series[0].points[1];

div.style.top = chart.plotSizeX - point.plotX + chart.plotTop + 'px';
div.style.left = chart.chartWidth + chart.plotLeft + 'px';
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0yztuxrp/

Comment: Please check my question. I have updated working and non-working sample.

Comment: For normal bar this is working. But for stacked bar, I don't know which position I have to take to fit the text parellel to the bars.

Comment: Use point's `plotX` property (as I did in my answer): https://plnkr.co/edit/z1lKfJviTXZuUTN7cVLR?p=preview